# how to disable SSL for samhain when connecting to a mysql database?

Tags: ssl, amazon-rds, my.cnf, ubuntu-20.04, mysql8

I have just compiled samhain from source and I added database connection credentials to the samhainrc file. For some reason, samhain will not write any entries to the mysql database.

The db credentials, which connect to a remote Amazon RDS instance, are correct. The remote machine runs MySQL 5.6 and must continue to do so to support a production website. The newly allocated machine on which samhain is running uses MySQL client 8. I can manually connect from this client machine if I disable ssl:

```
mysql -h db-server-xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u my_db_user -p --ssl-mode=DISABLED
```

If I don't disable ssl, I get an error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

These machines are running behind a firewall so there's no need for SSL. Unfortunately samhain appears to offer no configuration option to disable SSL for these connections.

Can someone help me get samhain to disable SSL/TLS for the database connection?  Or, alternatively, if I could make some configuration available to samhain which results in SSL or TLS working properly, that would be nice. I really hope I don't have to compile any such credentials into samhain itself because I hope to base other servers on this server's image and don't want to recompile samhain if connecting to some other database.